How can I inject content from one YAML file into a nested position in another YAML file using yq?
I have a file which i read using yq and I have to use the config in a kustomization template as yaml format.
So, the way I am reading the config from a file is below:
istio_ns_scoping_labels=$(yq -r '.cluster.config.istio_ns_scoping_labels' "$config_file" 2>/dev/null)
echo "$istio_ns_scoping_labels"

#istio_ns_scoping_labels
    [
  {
    "istio-discovery": "enabled"
  },
  {
    "kubernetes.io/metadata.name": "keycloak-idc-identity-broker"
  },
  {
    "kubernetes.io/metadata.name": "keycloak-idc-identity-broker-2"
  },
  {
    "kubernetes.io/metadata.name": "keycloak-idc-identity-broke-3"
  }
]

Now I want to format this as yaml so that I can substitute this into a yaml template as shown below
      discoverySelectors:
        - matchLabels:
            istio-discovery: enabled
        - matchLabels:
            kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker
        - matchLabels:
            kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker-2
        - matchLabels:
            kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker-3


I have to make sure that $labels is formatted properly as yaml format because I use envsubst to substitute the block as it is inside the template like below
    meshConfig:
      accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
      discoverySelectors:
        - matchLabels:
          ${MATCH_LABELS_BLOCK}

I am using yq to read the config of labels from a config.yml file as
config_file=cluster.yml
istio_ns_scoping_labels=$(yq -r '.cluster.config.istio_ns_scoping_labels' "$config_file" 2>/dev/null)

#cluster.yml
cluster:
  config:
    istio_ns_scoping_labels: 
      istio-discovery: enabled
      kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker


Show us your kustomization config

Re "a file which i read using yq": So why would you want to write a shell script to produce some YAML if you already have yq at hand?

kustomization_template.yml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
helmCharts:
- name: istiod
  repo: https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts
  version: ${ISTIO_VERSION}
  releaseName: istio-istiod
  valuesInline:
    pilot:
      image:
xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dockerhub/istio/pilot:1.24.1
      autoscaleMin: 3
      autoscaleMax: 15
      replicaCount: 3
    meshConfig:
      accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
      discoverySelectors:
        - matchLabels:
          ${MATCH_LABELS_BLOCK}

I want to do substitution of label

@pmf This is part of existing automation so I have to use shell script for it rather than any other language.

printf '%b\n' "$labels" instead of echo "$labels" if, as it appears, the \n should be translated to a single newline -- the behavior of echo is allowed by the standard to vary wildly, and is thus extremely implementation-dependent -- even if your shell is 100% certain to be bash it can be configured several different ways. See Why is printf better than echo? on [unix.se].

(if you don't want that translation, printf '%s\n' "$labels" is still better than echo "$labels", and much better than echo $labels -- that last echo string-splits on IFS and then expands globs, so its output can be very much unlike the input it resulted from).

This works fine but a caveat is that it is not indenting properly after newline
    meshConfig:       accessLogFile: /dev/stdout       discoverySelectors:         - matchLabels:             istio-discovery: enabled kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker
So, aftetr istio-discovery:enabled it goes to the newline but does not add tabs to indent it properly. I use cat "kustomization_template.yml" | envsubst > "kustomization.yml" to substitute the variable in the template

I'd be using yq itself to be doing the substitution. Using structure-unaware tools to edit structured documents is an invitation to bugs and corner cases.

...that said, there are two different tools (with entirely separate usage) named yq, and I'm not sure that you're telling us which of them you're using. Is this the yq that's a wrapper around jq, or is it the yq that's written ground-up in Go?

yq with a wrapper around jq

Okay. Could you please [edit] the question to have a better description of the value of $labels (one that isn't potentially corrupted by the side effects of echo $labels), so I can be sure that I'm testing my answer against something that matches your real data? (You can also use declare -p labels to print an exact definition of the value of the labels variable).

(ideally the document you want to substitute into would also be complete enough to allow a path to be built describing where in the document to substitute the data, since doing that from yq in a graceful way calls for knowing the names of the keys reaching all the way back to the root; the way discoverySelectors is indented implies that there are things left out; we don't want the whole document, but we do need everything required to build or test an answer).

I have modified the question a bit to include the edge case with yq as well .

I'd tend to argue that yq is correct when it ignores multiple values with the same key. That's not legit in a dictionary or map; any parser that generates or allows that is in undefined-behavior space.

How would we pick the thing entirely and substitute this object as is in the template?

Indeed, the YAML specification is explicit about that: It defines a mapping as an "an unordered association of unique keys to values"; notice the word "unique". So anything with duplicate keys isn't valid YAML at all.

It is fine so I edited the question to make the config change as     istio_ns_scoping_labels:        - istio-discovery: enabled       - kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker       - kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker-2       - kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broke-3

Good deal, I think this is answerable now.

(though your stated intended output seems off -- the data format in your JSON aligns with there being a - before each key: value pair, which would make sense for duplicates being allowed, but what's shown for expected output has duplicated keys in a single dictionary, vs a separate map for each key/value pair)

Would I be correct to assume that discoverySelectors lives inside spec: values: meshConfig:?

btw, see can't create multiple labels with the same key in Kubernetes 1.19. As far as I can tell, that limitation still exists today.

I think you are right. So, how can generate something like
meshConfig:
  discoverySelectors:
    - matchLabels:
        # Allow any namespaces with `istio-discovery=enabled`
        istio-discovery: enabled
    - matchLabels:
                    kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker
    - matchLabels:
                    kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker-2
    - matchLabels:
                    kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker-3



Given the jq-wrapper version of yq (which is the one you're working with),
yq -Y --argjson istio_ns_scoping_labels "$istio_ns_scoping_labels" '
  .spec.values.meshConfig.discoverySelectors = (
    $istio_ns_scoping_labels | map({matchLabels: .})
  )' - <cluster.yml

...properly emits output containing something like:
spec:
  values:
    meshConfig:
      discoverySelectors:
        - matchLabels:
            istio-discovery: enabled
        - matchLabels:
            kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker
        - matchLabels:
            kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker-2
        - matchLabels:
            kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broke-3


How did you get it?I am getting the error for the json input.
#cluster.yml
istio_ns_scoping_labels:
- istio-discovery: enabled
- kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker
- kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broker-2
- kubernetes.io/metadata.name: keycloak-idc-identity-broke-3
istio_ns_scoping_labels=$(yq -r '.cluster.config.istio_ns_scoping_labels' "$config_file" 2>/dev/null)
This does not produce the output for me and report the error as
jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson

Please don't try to stuff multi-line error reports into a comment -- the lack of formatting makes them pretty much unreadable. https://gist.github.com/ would make more sense. That said, before the command given was run, I already had instio_ns_scoping_labels assigned to contain the JSON given in your question.

@HemantKumar, ...that said, I think this may have just been a typo -- I was using instio, whereas your original question used istio as the beginning of the name of the variable with that content.
